# How to utilize a Pick[] command in a differential equation

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations

The code below is a simplified example of a problem I am working on.  I first define a relation `V` that depends on `x[t]` and `y[t]`, and I also define its derivative `Vx`. Next, I solve `V==0` for the variable `x[t]` in terms of `y[t]`:

```
V = x[t]^3 - (x[t] + y[t])^0.5;
Vx = D[V, x[t]];
x[t] = x[t] /. Solve[V == 0, x[t]];
Vx /. y[t] -> 20
```

The last expression shows that the vector `x[t]` has 6 elements.  However, I am only interested in the value of `x[t]` that corresponds to the smallest real value of `Vx`. The following commands choose this value and call it `x1[t]`:

```
Vx0 = (Vx /. x[t] -> #) &;
Vx1 = # &;
Vx2 = If[Abs[Im[Vx1[#]]] < 10^(-10), Re[Vx1[#]], 10^8] &;
Vx3 = Vx2[#] & /@ Vx;
x1[t] = Pick[x[t], Vx3, Min[Vx3]];
```

The last line gives me an error that the `Pick[]` expressions have incompatible shapes.  However, `Length[Vx3]` = `Length[x[t]` = 6. Moreover, I get a numerical solution upon specifying a value of `y[t]`.  For instance;

```
x1[t] /. y[t] -> 20
```

yields `{-1.62445138605743}`. I can also plot `x1[t]` as a function of `y[t]`:

```
Plot[{x1[t]}, {y[t], 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {-5, 5}, AspectRatio -> .5]
```

[image]

yields a nice graph. I am having two difficulties with this type of model. First, I cannot always get the Plot command to work properly in my more complex model.  Second, I cannot substitute `x1[t]` into a differential equation to solve it numerically:

```
soly = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == 
     0.05*y[t]*(1 - y[t]/50) - x1[t], y[0] == 70}, {y}, {t, 0, 20}];
```

does not work. Instead it tells me that I have incompatible shapes. I really thought this would work given that the numerical plot worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Rick! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

[`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects take a pure function and an index, and the indices are ordered so that real values come before complex values, and amongst the real values they are sorted in increasing order. Now, let's look at your `x[t]` (after rationalizing the exponent):

```
V = x^3 - (x + y)^(1/2);
x /. Solve[V == 0, x]
```

> {Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 1], Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 2], 
>    Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 3], Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 4], 
>    Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 5], Root[-y - #1 + #1^6 &, 6]}

If there is a minimum real root, it will be the first one above, so you can define:

```
x[t_] := Root[-y[t] - # + #^6&, 1]
```

Then, a plot of `x[t]` gives:

```
Plot[x[t], {y[t], 0, 50}, PlotRange->{-5,5}]
```

[image]

in agreement with your plot. Your ODE can use the above `x[t]`:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[t] == .05 y[t] (1-y[t]/50) - x[t], y[0]==70}, y, {t, 0, 20}];
```

Visualization:

```
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This did help.